# Devise, subdomains, and super users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I am using Basecamp-style subdomains for an app. Using Devise, I am allowing users access to only their subdomain by using the following in User.rb:

```
  def self.find_for_authentication(conditions={})
    conditions[:account_id] = Account.find_by_subdomain(conditions.delete(:subdomain)).id
    super(conditions)
  end
```

This checks to make sure the account associated with the user attempting to login matches the subdomain. It works fine.

My problem is that I want to allow super-users to login too... who will not have an associated 'Account'. They will instead have a "superuser' boolean column on the same 'User' model.

**Is there a way to check for the right subdomain OR 'superuser' status?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What if you made an Account for all superusers? I'm not sure what stage of the Auth process this gets called, but maybe something along these lines..?

```
def self.find_for_authentication(conditions={})
  if subdomain = conditions.delete(:subdomain)
    conditions[:account_id] = Account.find_by_subdomain(subdomain).id
  elsif User.where(conditions).where(:superuser => true).length > 0
    conditions[:account_id] = 1 # 1 is account reserved for super users
  end

  super(conditions)
en
```